# Is + a 3-ary relation?

Tags: logic, terminology

In notes that I am reading it states that + is a relation on $\mathbb{R}.$ They define a n-ary relation as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a n-ary function as a function that takes each n-tuple to a unique value in $\mathbb{R}.$ With these definitions, it seems that + is more of a function that a relation. But I guess + can be considered as a ternary relation with $(a, b, c) \in +$ if $a + b = c.$ Would this be a correct way of looking at this?

Comment: It is **one of the many** correct ways of looking at this.

Comment: To any function whatsoever there is an associated relation: if $f: X\rightarrow Y$, then the *graph of $f$* is the relation $G_f\subseteq X\times Y$ given by $xG_fy\iff f(x)=y$. (Conversely, if $R$ is a relation on $X\times Y$ such that for each $x\in X$ there is *exactly one* $y\in Y$ with $xRy$, then $R$ can be captured by a function $f_R: X\rightarrow Y$ given by $f_R(x)=y$ iff $xRy$.) And indeed, sometimes (in set theory for example) we identify a function with its graph, so that there's no difference at all between $f$ and $G_f$.

Comment: As an interesting note, it's worth pointing out that this "relationization" process can actually be useful! For instance, a powerful technique in mathematical logic for showing that two structures are "similar" in a precise sense (Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games) works best if the structures only involve relations; by replacing all functions with their graphs, we can make these games work for arbitrary settings.

Comment: + is more likely to be interpreted as a binary relation, with one of the inputs being a pair (a,b).  So it would be more like $((a, b), c) \in +$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$+$ is traditionally considered a binary operation (I believe the notes have a typo), but as you mention, there is an associated [ternary relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_relation), let's call it $R_+$ where $(a,b,c)\in R_+$ when $a+b=c$. This relation is special (like a function) in that the first two entries uniquely determine a third.